# Setting Ng-options default value

Tags: json, angularjs

How do I set the ng-options default value...

here is my ng-option directive:

```
ng-options="val as val for val in ticket_group.splits"
```

Comment: Is uour default value part of the array ?

Comment: yes... my im good with taking the index 0 from the array but I cant seem to get it to default... [2,4]

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-init`

```
<select ng-init="myModel = ticket_group.splits[0]" ng-model="myModel" ng-options="val as val for val in ticket_group.splits"></select>
```

or set the `myModel` value inside the controller,

```
$scope.myModel = ticket_group.splits[0]; // ticket_group.splits[1]; ticket_group.splits[2]; .. or what u need
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/vehakimusi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: tried that but it didnt work:   <select ng-model="ticket_quantity" ng-init="ticket_quantity = ticket_group.splits[0]" ng-options="val as val for val in ticket_group.splits"></select>

Comment: please post your `ticket_group.splits`

Comment: {{ticket_group.splits}} = [1,3] in the view

Comment: is that what you want to see?

Comment: I added a demo please check

Comment: thanks so i can get it to work with the test array but not with dynamic new quantities, how do I get that to work?